# Combining multiple INT columns to return a single date as a result in a query, how do I do this?

Tags: ms-access

I'm unfamiliar with MS Access and from what I have resesarched CVDate will not work, CONCAT doesn't work either, nor does using the & to combine them. I've tried to use the cast function but am unsure if I am doing this right.

```
SELECT cast(cast(TDay & TMonth & TYear as int) as datetime)
FROM NDX_FULL;
```

I'm trying to get the result of the query to come back as day/month/year.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DateSerial & Format function. See below:

```
SELECT Format(dateserial(TYear ,TMonth, TDay),"dd/mm/yyyy") as dt FROM NDX_FULL;
```

Comment: Is it supposed to return a dialog box when I return to datasheet view? Also the columns are filled with #Error.

Comment: No, this query will return the date in day/month/year format

Comment: @Icodin: double-check that field names are correct. Also `datetime` is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2), better use a different alias.

Answer (score 0):

A date *value* carries no format, so you should simply use:

```
Select DateSerial(TYear ,TMonth, TDay) As TDate From NDX_FULL
```

Then apply a format for display if/when needed.